# How to test the hypothesis for equality of variances through the Barlett test?

Tags: r, statistics

Request from the user and enter the number of time subintervals (2 or more). Divide the elements of the TT vector into a given number of connected, approximately equal subintervals. Calculate variance estimates on each subinterval. Using the Bartlett criterion to test the hypothesis of equality of variances on all subintervals – with the alternative "not equal". But while doing the task, I don't quite understand how to correctly test the hypothesis through the Barlett test

```
> TT
[1] 20.2 18.6 15.0 12.0 11.7 10.9  9.0 11.9 13.3  8.8  8.6  6.1  6.6  6.5 11.4

> n <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Enter count ints: "))
Enter count ints: 3
> n
[1] 3
> ints = split(TT, cut(seq_along(TT),n))
> ints
$`(0.981,7.33]`
[1] 20.2 18.6 15.0 12.0 11.7 10.9  9.0

$`(7.33,13.7]`
[1] 11.9 13.3  8.8  8.6  6.1  6.6

$`(13.7,20]`
[1]  6.5 11.4 12.9  5.4  2.5  4.3  3.0
> Var = lapply(ints,var)
> Var
$`(0.981,7.33]`
[1] 17.4081

$`(7.33,13.7]`
[1] 8.197667

$`(13.7,20]`
[1] 16.53905
```

Here is my opinion on how to decide further

```
> bartlett.test(ints,Var)

        Bartlett test of homogeneity of variances

data:  ints
Bartlett's K-squared = 0.77726, df = 2, p-value = 0.678
```

But it turns out that with a significance criterion of 0.05, H0 will not be rejected, that is the variances are the same, although according to the previous paragraph, they can be seen that they are different.

Am I doing everything right or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quite reproduce your posted results, and you seem to be making a mistake in applying `bartlett.test()`, but more fundamentally it appears that the segments of the vector you've defined **do not actually differ significantly in their variance according to the Bartlett test**.  That doesn't mean they "have the same variance" - first, you can never use frequentist tests to accept the null hypothesis, and second, your power to reject the null hypothesis depends on the test you're using.

### setup

```r
TT <- scan(text="20.2 18.6 15.0 12.0 11.7 10.9  9.0 11.9 13.3  8.8  8.6  6.1  6.6  6.5 11.4")
n <- 3
cc <- cut(seq_along(TT), n)
ints <- split(TT, cc)
sapply(ints, var)
(0.986,5.67]  (5.67,10.3]    (10.3,15] 
      14.660        3.677        4.903
```

These variances *appear* quite different - the first group has four times the variance of the second group and 3x the variance of the third!  However:

```r
bartlett.test(ints)

    Bartlett test of homogeneity of variances

data:  ints
Bartlett's K-squared = 2.033, df = 2, p-value = 0.3619
```

That says that the differences in the variance are *consistent with* sets of values of this size that all came from a distribution with the same variance.

As an experiment, let's look at the distribution of variance ratios of two standard Normal samples of size 5:

```r
vfun <- function(n) { vr <- var(rnorm(n))/var(rnorm(n)); max(vr, 1/vr) }
set.seed(101)
r <- replicate(10000, vfun(5))
hist(log10(r))
```

[image]

You can see that variance ratios greater than sqrt(10) approx 3.2 (i.e. log10(x) == 0.5) are common, and variance ratios greater than 10 are not that unusual. In fact, if we compute `mean(r>10)` (the fraction of runs with variance ratio > 10), that's just about 0.05 - so you would have to see a **tenfold** variance ratio in order to reject the null hypothesis at the usual p=0.05 level ...